# Using shiny with stat_function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to apply my function in stat_function in ggplot2 and then use shiny to get an interactive figure. I tried my best. I struggled to do it as a newcomer to shinny. Here is what I have done so far, but it does not work

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("letters"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$b("Data:"),
      textInput("x", "x", value = "D,B,C", placeholder = "Enter letter separated by a comma, D,B,C"),

 textInput("x", "x", value = "D,B,C", placeholder = "Enter letter separated by a comma, D,B,C"),    
),         
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    
    
    
   ko <- function(x,D,B,C) { 
    D*B*(x-C)^2

    } 
    ggplot(data.frame(x = c(10, 100)), aes(x = x)) + 
      stat_function(fun = ko, args = list(D=2,B=3,C=-4), aes(colour = "curve1")) +
      stat_function(fun = ko, args = list(D=1.5,B=2,C=3) , aes(colour = "Curve2")) +
      scale_colour_manual("Variable", values = c("red", "blue"))+
      
      theme_bw()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have edited my codes. I get the plot, but when I replace the numbers with letters does not work. The other issue is that there are two curves.

Comment: If I understand your question, you wanted to replace the `D, B C` based on the input values from `textInput`

Comment: That's correct. when I put  different numbers (D, B, C) I would get different plot

Comment: Let' say, you have only 'D,B', in that case, what will be the value of C?  From the function, showed, all of these ('D', B, C) have value passed into

Comment: You could  just consider it  as a number, a constant

Comment: My point is that you are only changing it with in `aes(x)` and that should be `aes(input$x)`, but these are strings "D,B",   Not clear how that changes the `stat_function` based on the input

Comment: It is a bit confusing from the example, because you are creating a data.frame with column name 'x' as well as the `textInput` is 'x'

Comment: Did you meant the column name to be the output of textInput?

Comment: From the example, you are calling the `stat_function` twice with different values.  I am not sure whether you need to subset the `D, B, C` that goes into the stat_function i.e. if the input is `D,B`, then how do you want the function to change from `stat_function(fun = M, args = list(D=4,B=7,C=2))`

Comment: My understanding is that  you could generate several curves using stat-function with different values

Comment: Yes, it can.  Sorry, I couldn't get the logic correctly

Comment: I have edited the codes with a better function.

Comment: Copying code as snippet is not really useful for R. It doesn't add any value. You can copy your code as it is as a text.